# Eliminate default zeros while creating string from byte array

Tags: java, string

I am getting bytes from IOStream and converting it to string. From that string i am extracting a sequence using substring api.

Size of ByteArray is 128 bytes. If the stream contains only 10 bytes and remaining are filled with zero[initially filled]. I am converting the byte array to string by passing to a string constructor new String(byte[]) and checking the length. The length is 128. Why it is showing 128? Actually it should show for 10 byte character length.
How to eliminate the zero while converting to string. Is there any api's to eliminate the default zeros in byte array. It's creating problem while creating a substring from the constructed string.

```
    byte[] b = { 99, 116, 101, 100, 46, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0}
 System.out.println("byte length = " + b.length);
            String str;
            try {
                str = new String(b, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("String length = " + str.length());
                System.out.println(str);
                System.out.println("  ## substring  =  " + str.substring(0));
                System.out.println(" substring length = "
                        + str.substring(0).length());
                System.out.println("Done......");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }0, 0, 0 };
```

Comment: loop from the back of the array, until you find the **first** non-zero  `Byte`. Use that index in the [other `String` ctor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Comment: If i do substring(0,bytesRead) then i may get stringindexoutofboundsexception because in utf-8 some special characters will take two bytes for a character.

Comment: @Boris  i can't predict which zero it is.either default size zero or else zero from inputstream?

Comment: If you say you're chunking it into `128` byte segments, then for each segment you know that padding starts from the end. If you work backwards then the padding ends when the first non-zero `byte` is read.

Comment: @Shriram - Can we see how your getting the byte[] from your InputStream. You need a way to differential. Is there some way to get a correctly sized byte[] directly rather than always getting a byte[128]?

Comment: This does seem to be a bit of an XY problem. You want to read data from an InputStream as text. But your question posted is about problems you have run into in the solution you are attempting. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) from an `InputStream`, it will tell you how many bytes were read. The length of the `byte[]` itself is mostly irrelevant (other than defining the max number of bytes which could be read in a single call). There should be no need to later go examine the `byte[]` to try and determine how much of the data is relevant. Pay attention to the return value from [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) and use that when creating a `String`.

Additionally, if all of your data is text, consider using an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), perhaps in combination with a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Answer (score 4):

To create a String from part of a byte array, use the constructor `String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, String charsetName)`. Example:

```
// uses the first 10 bytes of b
str = new String(b, 0, 10, "UTF-8");
```

Also, if you're compiling for Java 7 you might as well use `StandardCharsets` (from the `java.nio.charset` package), and avoid having to handle `UnsupportedEncodingException`. Example:

```
str = new String(b, 0, 10, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: +1 If you only want to convert 10 bytes, tell it to convert 10 bytes and you don't need to zero out the bytes you didn't read.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be like this

```
  byte[] b = { 99, 116, 101, 100, 46, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0};

        int nonZeroPos=0;
        for (int i = b.length-1; i >0; i--) {
            if(b[i]!=0){
                nonZeroPos=i;
                 break;
            }
        }


        System.out.println("byte length = " + b.length);
        String str;
        try {
             str = new String(b, 0, nonZeroPos, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("String length = " + str.length());
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println("  ## substring  =  " + str.substring(0));
            System.out.println(" substring length = "
                    + str.substring(0).length());
            System.out.println("Done......");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You also could have it done this way -

```
 String zerostring = new String(new byte[]{0});
 str=new String(b).replace(zerostring , "");
 System.out.println(str);
```

But disadvantage of this is it will replace 0s coming in the word.

Answer (score 0):

First an explanation.

Not every byte sequence is valid UTF-8. A binary byte 0 (0x00) is valid, and does not terminate a String as in C.

In fact a terminating `\0` was later deplored by either C's Kernighan or Ritchie, as being suboptimal.

To prevent problems, not only Unicode code points above U+007F (0x7f) are multi-byte encoded (whith high bits of bytes set), but also U+0000 in [Java's UTF-8, DataOutputSream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29).

```
byte[] bytes = get UTF-8 bytes from string
```

Now bytes could have a multi-byte sequence for the code point 0.

So you might either clean up the bytes, a small loop, or clean up the string:

```
str = str.replace("\u0000", ""); // All bytes 0
str = str.replaceFirst("\u0000+$", ""); // Only trailing bytes 0, regex
```